# asterisk Google contacts

Tags: asterisk

I am looking for a way to sync my contacts with asterisk's database. At the movement I am using it manually with database put cid command. The system runs asterisk 11 and it without GUI. That job will run at regular intervals in a day. Is there a script for that?

Answer (score 0):

There are ALOT of scripts can be googled. But you should at least say how your current contacts stored. Simplest script is lookup via func_odbc in any odbc-supported database.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. As I mentioned before I do store the contacts in local asterisk's dB by making use the command database put cid command.

Comment: Could you please mention the func_odbc solution you mentioned, please? I could use the mysql in work.

Comment: It fairly simple. Not think someone publish so simple solution on web. http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+func+func_odbc